# $pull operation in MongoDB not working for me

Tags: mongodb

I have a document with the following key-array pair:

```
"home" : [
        "Kevin Garnett",
        "Paul Pierce",
        "Rajon Rondo",
        "Brandon Bass",
        " 5 sec inbound",
        "Kevin Seraphin"
    ]
```

I want to remove the element `" 5 sec inbound"` from the array and use the following command (in the MongoDB shell):

```
>coll.update({},{"$pull":{"home":" 5 sec inbound"}})
```

This is not working as verified by a query:

```
>coll.findOne({"home":/5 sec inbound/})
"home" : [
        "Kevin Garnett",
        "Paul Pierce",
        "Rajon Rondo",
        "Brandon Bass",
        " 5 sec inbound",
        "Kevin Seraphin"
    ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hmm this works.  Could be a white space issue on your end.  You can use a regex query. Also turn on the safe parameter for a sanity check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That very same statement works for me:

```
> db.test.insert({"home" : [
...         "Kevin Garnett",
...         "Paul Pierce",
...         "Rajon Rondo",
...         "Brandon Bass",
...         " 5 sec inbound",
...         "Kevin Seraphin"
...     ]})
> db.test.find({"home":/5 sec inbound/}).count()
1
> db.test.update({},{"$pull":{"home":" 5 sec inbound"}})
> db.test.find({"home":/5 sec inbound/}).count()
0
```

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out why this is not working for me. Argh.